# Testing: mocking node-fetch dependency that it is used in a class method

Tags: testing, sinon, stub, ava

I have the following situation:

A.js

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import httpClient from './myClient/httpClient'

 export default class{
    async init(){
       const response = await fetch('some_url')
       return httpClient.init(response.payload)
    }
}
```

A_spec.js

```
import test from 'ava'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import httpClient from './myClient/httpClient'
import A from './src/A'

test('a async test', async (t) => {
    const instance = new A()
    const stubbedHttpInit = sinon.stub(httpClient, 'init')
    sinon.stub(fetch).returns(Promise.resolve({payload: 'data'})) //this doesn't work

    await instance.init()
    t.true(stubbedHttpInit.init.calledWith('data'))
})
```

My idea it's check if the httpClient's init method has been called using the payload obtained in a fetch request.

My question is: **How I can mock the fetch dependency for stub the returned  value when i test the A's init method?**

Answer (score 14):

Finally I resolved this problem stubbing the `fetch.Promise` reference like this:

```js
sinon.stub(fetch, 'Promise').returns(Promise.resolve(responseObject))
```

the explanation for this it's that `node-fetch` have a reference to the native Promise and when you call `fetch()`, this method returns a `fetch.Promise`.

Comment: This does not work for typescript. I get the following error when I try to write the exact code mentioned above: Argument of type '"Promise"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"isRedirect"'.

Comment: Tocayo: what's the actual responseObject?  Seem's like your reference link is no longer accurate to the line you meant as line #37 is  just a blank line

Comment: Thank you! I looked at many SO answers, majority of them using `proxyquire`. This one is the most simple one.

Comment: @Avneesh late to the party, but it works in typescript if you typecast it as any: spyOn(fetch, 'Promise' as any)

Answer (score 4):

You can stub `fetch()` as decribed [in the manual](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/stub-dependency/)

```
import sinon from 'sinon'
import * as fetchModule from 'node-fetch'
import { Response } from 'node-fetch'
// ...
const stub = sinon.stub(fetchModule, 'default')
stub.returns(new Promise((resolve) => resolve(new Response(undefined, { status: 401 }))))
// ...
stub.restore()
```

Note, that `fetch()` is the default export from `node-fetch` so you neeed to stub `default`.

Answer (score 3):

`sinon.stub(fetch)` can't stub a function itself. Instead you need to stub the `node-fetch` dependency from inside `./src/A`, perhaps using something like [`proxyquire`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire):

```
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire`
const A = proxyquire('./src/A', {
  'node-fetch': sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve({payload: 'data'}))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but finally i've resolved this without external dependencies. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@mrtnlrsn's answer does not work for files generated from TypeScript in NodeJS, because `default` is a generated property, each module which imports such a dependency has its own, so stubbing one does not affect others.

However, NodeJS gives access to imported modules, so stubbing works this way:

```js
const nodeFetchPath = require.resolve("node-fetch");
const nodeFetchModule = require.cache[nodeFetchPath];
assert(nodeFetchModule);
const stubNodeFetch = sinon.stub(nodeFetchModule, "exports");
```

Make sure you use the same `node-fetch` module as the tested module, e.g. using `yarn dedupe`. Or build your own `nodeFetchPath`.

Comment: Works for @mrtnlrsn in typescript :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found it useful to preserve the `node-fetch` functionality since my mock responses were already being supplied via [`nock`](https://github.com/node-nock/nock)

To accomplish this, I proxyquire'd the dependency as described in the answer above but wrapped a require call in a spy:

```
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire'
import { spy } from 'sinon'

const fetchSpy = spy(require('node-fetch'))
const moduleA = proxyquire(
  './moduleA',
 { 'node-fetch': fetchSpy }
)
```

...

```
expect(fetchSpy.args).toBe(...)
```